# Opening time of an excel file

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

My client sent me a 13M Excel file, it contains data, formulas, charts, and [group/ungroup rows/columns](http://helpdeskgeek.com/office-tips/group-rows-and-columns-in-an-excel-worksheet-to-make-information-more-readable/).

When I use Excel for Windows to open it, it takes `51 seconds` to open it. Then the recalculation by `Ctrl+Alt+F9` takes `35 seconds`. But when I go through each sheets and press `Shift+F9`, only one sheet takes several seconds, and the others are quite fast.

So my questions are:

1) what elements may make `opening` a spreadsheet slow?

2) why the recalculation takes much more time than the sum of calculation of each sheet, given that the dependence tree is already built?

Comment: There could be a number of answers, "formulas", without knowing things like are these inefficient formula, eg complete column array formula, or simple efficient formula.  You can save the workbook as a web page format, and see which individual sheet is bloated for any possible corruption etc.

Comment: If it is due to inefficient formulas, I don't see why `opening` takes much more time than the full `recalculation`, and why the full `recalculation` takes much more time than the sum of each worksheet...

Comment: Do calculations happen between sheets?

Comment: Take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff700515(v=office.14).aspx Everything you need to know about calculation times

Comment: `Opening`, as the name says for itself, includes the opening of file, which means that it have to be copied from disk to memory. Depending on your hard drive it can be faster or not. After the file is opened, then Excel calculate all formulas on it. When you tell Excel to `recalculate`, the file is already in memory, so that's why takes less time.